# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token for a user defined class in the source file

Tags: c++

I am facing an error in one of my projects which I have replicated using a standalone program. I did see several posts pertinent to this, but could not figure out my problem. I am getting the following error with this code : "error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class X
{
private:
    int _x;
public:
    X(int x) : _x(x) {};
};

class Y
{
private:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<X> X_ptr;
public:
    X_ptr& func1();
};

X_ptr& Y::func1()
{
   X_ptr p(new X(8));
   return p;
};

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

Can someon help me with in resolving this error?

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems. First, you forgot to qualify the type name `X_ptr`:

```
    Y::X_ptr& Y::func1()
//  ^^^     ^
//          BUT REMOVE THIS!
```

Second, notice that you are returning a *reference* to a local variable. Attempting to dereference the value returned by `func1()` will give you undefined behavior.

Just change the prototype of your function this way:

```
Y::X_ptr Y::func1()
// ^^^^^
// Returning the smart pointer by value now
{
    X_ptr p(new X(8));
    return p;
}
```

Comment: @deepaktj: Does this answer your question?